# Paperclip, aws, heroku, Tokyo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I passed one day to try and search how to configure paperclip on Heroku with AWS, but I can't.

My bucket locality is Tokyo so s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com

That are my folders (emangakaimg is my bucket)

```
#initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = 'emangakaimg.s3.amazonaws.com'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'

#config/environments/production.rb
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
  }

#models/materiel.rb
class Materiel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :materielcategory

    has_attached_file :couverture, :styles => { :hd => "1920x1080#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :couverture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end

#controllers/materiels_controller.rb
    def materiel_params
      params.require(:materiel).permit(:couverture, :title, :content, :materielcategory_id)
    end
```

What my mistakes please ?
heroku config:set are configurated

Thank you very much

Comment: Is there some error output?

Comment: Thank you. No, just 404 error after submit. How I can show the errors ?